# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas_datareader.utils'

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-datareader

I am trying to utilize pandas data reader in my program

```
from pandas_datareader import data 
from pandas_datareader.utils import RemoteDataError
```

but when i run it a get an error

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\compat\__init__.py:7: FutureWarning: pandas.util.testing is deprecated. Use the functions in the public API at pandas.testing instead.
  from pandas.util.testing import assert_frame_equal
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\tradingBOT.py", line 2, in <module>
    from pandas_datareader.utils import RemoteDataError
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas_datareader.utils'
```

I used pip to install `pandas-datareader` and it worked without a problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of typing this:

```
    from pandas_datareader.utils import RemoteDataError
```

I tried this:

```
    from pandas_datareader._utils import RemoteDataError
```

I don't know if there's a difference, but everything seems to be working!